# В чем проблема в решении задачи?

Tags: python

друзья, изучая программирование столкнулся с проблемой. В ide код работает и с любыми значениями и выдает правильный результат. При отправке кода на платформу stepic код выдает такую ошибку:

```
Failed test #4 of 15. Runtime error
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 7, in <module>
    if a[b] != a[c]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Мой код, который работает в IDE, но на который ругается Stepic

```py
a = input()
b = 0
c = 1
v = 1
x = 1
while x <= len(a):
    if a[b] != a[c]:
        print(a[b],v, sep="", end="")
        v = 0
    if x+1 == int(len(a)):
        print(a[c],v+1 , sep="", end="")
        break
    b += 1
    c += 1
    v += 1
    x += 1
```

```
Sample Input 1:

aaaabbcaa
Sample Output 1:

a4b2c1a2
Sample Input 2:

abc
Sample Output 2:

a1b1c1
```

Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать, заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Желательно бы еще приложить описание задачи. Падает у вас из-за того что тест не может быть пройден, проверяемое значение выходит за границы массива

Comment: введите в a один символ

Comment: Как вариант можно попробовать добавить
a = [char for char in a] после инпута

Comment: @tonysdev зачем - строка прекрасно итерируется?

Comment: @splash58 непонятно как проходит тестирование, да и было бы идеально ему приложить суть задачи

Comment: суть задачит понятна из кода - собрать повторяющиеся буквы в буква+количество `abc => a1b1c1`

Comment: Но если задать просто одну букву, этот код упадет

Comment: @splash58 Я про ограничения, задача то понятна)

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код при введённой строке, если она состоит всего из одного символа, вылетит на строке `if a[b] != a[c]:` потому что `c` изначально равно 1, а `a[1]` находится за границей строки из одного символа.

Мой вариант.

```
a = input()
c = 1
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    if a[i] == a[i-1]:
        c += 1
    else:
        print(a[i-1], c , sep="", end="")
        c = 1
if a:
    print(a[-1], c, sep="")
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, что уделили внимание. Это ценно!

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код ошибается на строке из одного символа (падает из-за обращения за конец строки). Ещё не хватает перевода строки в конце, но это не существенно.

Если чинить ваш вариант, то нужно обработать строку из одного элемента, удалить дублирующиеся счётчики, убрать дублированную печать. Получится что-то такое:

```
a = input()
s = 1 # размер текущей группы
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i + 1 == len(a) or a[i] != a[i + 1]:
        print(a[i], s, sep='', end='')
        s = 0
    s += 1
print()
```

В Питоне для алгоритмов работающих с группами одинаковых элементов есть [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

print(''.join(
    f'{c}{sum(1 for _ in g)}'
    for c, g in itertools.groupby(input())
))
```

Comment: Огонь, большое спасибо!